# MQ listener on different queues: How to determine which queue triggered it

Tags: c#, .net, listener, ibm-mq

I have this MQ listener code implemented:

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program app = new Program();
            app.Setup();
            Console.ReadLine();
    
        }
    
        public void Setup()
        {
            XMSFactoryFactory xff = XMSFactoryFactory.GetInstance(XMSC.CT_WMQ);
            IConnectionFactory cf = xff.CreateConnectionFactory();
            cf.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_HOST_NAME, "10.87.188.156(7111)");
            cf.SetIntProperty(XMSC.WMQ_PORT, 7111);
            cf.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_CHANNEL, "QMEIGS1.CRM.SVRCONN");
            cf.SetIntProperty(XMSC.WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE, XMSC.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);
            cf.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_QUEUE_MANAGER, "QMEIGS1");
            cf.SetIntProperty(XMSC.WMQ_BROKER_VERSION, XMSC.WMQ_BROKER_V1);
    
            IConnection conn = cf.CreateConnection();
            Console.WriteLine("connection created");
            ISession sess = conn.CreateSession(false, AcknowledgeMode.AutoAcknowledge);
            IDestination dest = sess.CreateQueue("DOX.APYMT.ESB.SSK.RPO.02");
            IMessageConsumer consumer = sess.CreateConsumer(dest);
            MessageListener ml = new MessageListener(OnMessage);
            consumer.MessageListener = ml;
            conn.Start();
            Console.WriteLine("Consumer started");
    
    
        }
    
        private void OnMessage(IMessage msg)
        {
            ITextMessage textMsg = (ITextMessage)msg;
            Console.Write("Got a message: ");
            Console.WriteLine(textMsg.Text);
        }
    
    }
```

This works fine and is triggered when putting something on the queue.
However, I need to listen to multiple queues and except writing a separate an OnMessage_zzz(IMessage msg) for each queue, I don't seem to be able to determine how to find out which queue triggered this. I examined the msg variable, but can't find any reference there. Is there a way to make it dynamic, or do I need to have a separate OnMessage for each queue?

Something like:

```
            private void OnMessage(IMessage msg)
            {
                string queue = ???;
                ProcessQueue(queue);
                ITextMessage textMsg = (ITextMessage)msg;
                Console.Write("Got a message: ");
                Console.WriteLine(textMsg.Text);
            }
```

Comment: Does it help to use the SessionAwareMessageListener instead of just the MessageListener ?

Answer (score 0):

To implement only one single OnMessage method, wrap it into a class which additionally stores the queue name. You would need to create an instance of it for each of your listener.

```
[...]
       MessageProcessor mp = new MessageProcessor("DOX.APYMT.ESB.SSK.RPO.02");
       MessageListener ml = new MessageListener(mp.OnMessage);
[...]

class MessageProcessor
{
    private string queueName;

    public MessageProcessor(aQueueName)
    {
        queueName = aQueueName;
    }

    public void OnMessage(IMessage msg)
    {
        ITextMessage textMsg = (ITextMessage)msg;
        Console.Write("Got a message from Queue " + queueName + ": ");
        Console.WriteLine(textMsg.Text);
    }
}
```